# Dynamically EasyDropDown.js select

Tags: select

I use easydropdown.js to style the HTML select.
The problem is that populating dynamically select via $.post jquery, the script does not work.
You know how to help me? Thanks.

Comment: Please show some code

Answer (score 1):

We can get `select` object, modify its value, and then `destroy` and re-init as code below:

```
<select id="select-to-easydropdown" class="dropdown">
  <option value="option1">option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">option 2</option>
</select>

/* in js code with jquery */

var select = $("#select-to-easydropdown");

// process with select object (add/remove option)
select.append('<option value="option3">option 3</option>');

// destroy if existing easydropdown object
select.easyDropDown('destroy');

// init or re-init easydropdown
select.easyDropDown({
    onChange: function(selected){       
      // add change event listener
      ...
    }    
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
var choose = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
        var wait = '<option value="0">wait...</option>';

        $("#select_2").html(choose);

        $("#select_3").html(choose);



        $("#select_1").change(function(){
            var val_select_1 = $("#select_1 option:selected").attr('value');
            $("#select_2").html(wait);
            $("#select_2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#select_3").html(choose);
            $("#select_3").attr("disabled", "disabled");

            $.post("select.php", {id_select_1:value_select_1}, function(data){
                $("select#select_2").removeAttr("disabled"); 
                $("select#select_2").html(data);

            });
        }); 

        $("#select_2").change(function(){
            $("#select_3").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#select_3").html(wait);
            var val_select_2 = $("#select_2 option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select.php", {id_select_2:value_select_2}, function(data){
                $("#select_3").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#select_3").html(data);
            });
        });
```

and select style this https://github.com/patrickkunka/easydropdown